# How to access object property with a string?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I access `this.resources.language` in the `setLanguage()` function, with property current language that is one of those four from resources?

```
myLanguage = new Language( 'en' );

function Language (currentLanguage) {
  this.currentLanguage = currentLanguage;
  this.resources = {
    en: {
        latest_songs_heading: "Latest",
        popular_songs_heading: "Popular",
    },
    de: {
        latest_songs_heading: "Neueste",
        popular_songs_heading: "Beliebteste",
    },
    es: {
        latest_songs_heading: "Más reciente",
        popular_songs_heading: "El mas popular",
    },
    po: {
        latest_songs_heading: "Mais recentes",
        popular_songs_heading: "O mais popular",
    }
  },
  this.getLanguage = function() {
    return 'Current language: ' + this.currentLanguage;
  }
  this.setLanguage = function() {
    var language = this.currentLanguage;
    return this.resources.language;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
return this.resources[language];
```